# Skill doesn't trigger the lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am in the US and I use the Alexa app on my phone.

I have created a skill with ID amzn1.ask.skill.cb02c2fe-37a1-4a37-b664-01fe31eead34
I have created a lambda with ARN arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:417818614074:function:pygarage

In the lambda I have added 3 triggers:

1. Alexa Smart Home
2. Alexa Skills Kit
3. API gateway

I have also tested with only "ash" or "ask" with the same result.
When I ask Alexa "discover devices": the lambda is never triggered.

When I do a curl on my laptop to the API gateway URL, the lambda is triggered.

I don't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had asked in parallel Alexa customer support for help, and they told me:

> Please note that to test your “In development” skill, you have to log in to the Alexa app using the same account with which you logged in to the developer console, which is xxx.

I had used a different account to create the Skill. I have now the same account in Alexa app and in the Skill developer console, and the lambda does get called.